# Regex to split "&" in URL parameters only if they are followed by content ending with "="

Tags: c#, regex

I have a dilemma that I have been attempting to resolve with malformed URL's, where specific parameters can have values that contain specific characters that might conflict with parsing the url.

```
if( remaining.Contains( "?" ) || remaining.Contains( "#" ) )
{
    if( remaining.Contains( "?" ) )
    {

        Path = remaining.Substring( 0, temp = remaining.IndexOf( "?" ) );

        remaining = remaining.Substring( temp + 1 );

        // Re-encode for URLs
        if( remaining.Contains( "?" ) )
        {
            remaining = URL.Substring( URL.IndexOf( "?" ) + 1 );
        }

        if( remaining.IndexOf("=") >= 0 )
        {
            string[] qsps = Regex.Split( remaining, @"[&]\b" );// Original Method: remaining.Split( '&' );
            qsps.ToList().ForEach( qsp =>
            {
                string[] vals = qsp.Split( '=' );
                if( vals.Length == 2 )
                {
                    Parameters.Add( vals[0], vals[1] );
                }
                else
                {
                    string key = (string) vals[0].Clone();
                    vals[0] = "";
                    Parameters.Add( key, String.Join( "=", vals ).Substring( 1 ) );
                }
            } );
        }
}
```

I added the line "**Regex.Split( remaining, @"[&]\b" );**" to grab "&" that were followed by a character, which seems useful.

**I am just trying to see if there is a better approach to only splitting the "&'s" that are actually for parameters?**

---

**Example to test against (which caused this needed update):**

> www.myURL.com/shop/product?utm_src=bm23&utm_med=email&utm_term=apparel&utm_content=02/15/2016&utm_campaign=Last
>   Chance! Presidents' Day Sales Event: Free Shipping & More!

A working regex should only grab the &'s for the following:

- utm_src=btm23
- utm_med=email
- utm_term=apparel
- utm_content=02/15/2016
- utm_campaign=Last Chance! Presidents' Day Sales Event: Free Shipping & More!

It should NOT count the "& More" as a match, since the section does not end with "=" afterwards

Comment: I wouldn't use split for this. A simple regex match should do it.

Comment: I am spitting the & to grab the param and value, but trying to avoid the case where a value might contain an "&" within it and having that also try to be split; which triggers that else and can throw an exception since the methods that parse those params would not be able to read it. >.<

Comment: @Doodely, you can use regex lookbehind and it will work as you expected. see my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a regex using a look-ahead:

```
/&(?=[^&=]+=)/
```

You can see this in effect here: [version1](https://regex101.com/r/fZ6bR5/1). It looks first for the `&` character, and then "peeks" forward to ensure that a `=` follows, but only if it does not contain another `&` or a `=` in between.

You can also ensure that there are no whitespace characters (like newlines, etc.) which aren't valid in URLs anyway ([version 2](https://regex101.com/r/fZ6bR5/2)):

```
&(?=[^\s&=]+=)
```

Comment: Both yours and @Saleem used look[behind] | [ahead] versions and I will be testing both since they seem to accomplish the same idea! I will update with what I find and mark accordingly :)

Comment: This gives me as match 4x `&` [see here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%26(%3f%3d%5b%5e%5cs%26%3d%5d%2b%3d)&i=www.myURL.com%2fshop%2fproduct%3futm_src%3dbm23%26utm_med%3demail%26utm_term%3dapparel%26utm_content%3d02%2f15%2f2016%26utm_campaign%3dLast+Chance!+Presidents%27+Day+Sales+Event%3a+Free+Shipping+%26+More!)

Comment: This solution worked very well for also including params after values that had whitespaces within them.

Ex) www.site.com/account/login/?test=This & Another Good One!&what=1 it matched the "&what=1" section where the other solutions were having issues. So, I might be continuing with this one. I will let you know :)

Comment: @Doodely a valid URL will never have any naked spaces in its parameters unless encoded. Please search and you'll find tons of posts here on stack overflow and rest of web. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp so said that there is no problem with suggested solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to use this regex:

```
Regex.Split(url, @"(?<=(?:=\S+?))&", 
   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

if you pass your test string via url which is.

`www.myURL.com/shop/product?utm_src=bm23&utm_med=email&utm_term=apparel&utm_content=02/15/2016&utm_campaign=Last Chance! Presidents' Day Sales Event: Free Shipping & More!`

The output should be.

```
www.myURL.com/shop/product?utm_src=bm23
utm_med=email
utm_term=apparel
utm_content=02/15/2016
utm_campaign=Last Chance! Presidents' Day Sales Event: Free Shipping & More!
```

Please note first line of output.

```
www.myURL.com/shop/product?utm_src=bm23
```

which contains first path of url, but can be easily splitted by `?`

Comment: That `(?<=...)` look-behind isn't valid in Javascript: it only supports look-aheads.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you see asker is using C# so it's valid in .net. I'v also posted answer in C#

Comment: Ah; my mistake. I somehow thought this was a Javascript question instead of C#/.NET. Apologies.

Comment: Oh no, no. no need to apologize. Actually, your comment will help a lot of other people who might be facing this kind of problem.

Comment: This seems to be working very well and you subsequently also taught me how valuable negative-lookbehinds were! I will do some further testing and if this seems solid, I'll mark it as accepted :)!!

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=[?&])([^&]*)(?=.*[&=])`

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=[?&])` positive lookbehind for either '&' or '?'
- `([^&]*)` capture as many characters as possible that aren't '&'
- `(?=.*[&=])` positive lookahead for either an '&' or '='

**Output:**

- utm_src=bm23
- utm_med=email
- utm_term=apparel
- utm_content=02/15/2016
- utm_campaign=Last Chance! Presidents' Day Sales Event: Free Shipping

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5b%3f%26%5d)(%5b%5e%26%5d*)(%3f%3d.*%5b%26%3d%5d)&i=www.myURL.com%2fshop%2fproduct%3futm_src%3dbm23%26utm_med%3demail%26utm_term%3dapparel%26utm_content%3d02%2f15%2f2016%26utm_campaign%3dLast+Chance!+Presidents%27+Day+Sales+Event%3a+Free+Shipping+%26+More!)

So to get the matches:

```
string str = "www.myURL.com/...";
Regex reg = "(?<=[?&])([^&]*)(?=.*[&=])";
List<string> result = reg.Matches(str).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
```

**Edit for the question edit**:

`(?<=[?&])\S.*?(?=&\S)|(?<=[?&])\S.*(?=\s)`

Comment: Realizing it now, there are so many incredibly detailed approaches to matching the correct type and use of "&"

I will be testing these since the implementation could be very useful for the site as a whole as well as future sites that might utilize this same logic.

I believe the spaces were the biggest issues affecting the correct match. So potentially making it to where it only matches "&" up to the first space it finds and not matching anything after could be useful


Ex) www.site.com/account/login/?test=This & Another Good One!&what=1 (it would match &what= [white space prior])

Comment: @Doodely yes, it's fun to fiddle around with it, I think I just need something to match end of string now

Comment: I updated my question since I kind of made it unclear by saying "it shouldn't include & More". I mean to phrase that as, it shouldn't count "& More!" as a match since there is a space.

Comment: @Doodely I think I found it: `(?<=[?&])\S.*?(?=&\S)|(?<=[?&])\S.*(?=\s)`. Works perfectly for both the strings you provided: [demo1](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5b%3f%26%5d)%5cS.*%3f(%3f%3d%26%5cS)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5b%3f%26%5d)%5cS.*(%3f%3d%5cs)&i=www.site.com%2faccount%2flogin%2f%3ftest%3dThis+%26+Another+Good+One!%26what%3d1%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a)

Comment: [demo2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5b%3f%26%5d)%5cS.*%3f(%3f%3d%26%5cS)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5b%3f%26%5d)%5cS.*(%3f%3d%5cs)&i=www.myURL.com%2fshop%2fproduct%3futm_src%3dbm23%26utm_med%3demail%26utm_term%3dapparel%26utm_content%3d02%2f15%2f2016%26utm_campaign%3dLast+Chance!+Presidents%27+Day+Sales+Event%3a+Free+Shipping+%26+More!%0d%0a%0d%0a)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to find errant
ampersands, this is a good regex for that.

`&(?=[^&=]*(?:&|$))`

You could either replace with a `%26` or split with it.
If you split with it, just recombine and the errant ampersand will be gone.